# Get predicted values using cross_validate()

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, cross-validation

I have the following code which performs 5-fold cross validation and returns several metric values.

```
iris = load_iris()
clf = SVC()
scoring = {'acc': 'accuracy',
           'prec_macro': 'precision_macro',
           'rec_micro': 'recall_macro'}
scores = cross_validate(clf, iris.data, iris.target, scoring=scoring,
                         cv=5, return_train_score=True)
```

I want to know if this can be modified to print the predicted values for each fold.

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using sklearn

Answer (score 2):

If you're using sklearn you can use `cross_val_predict`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(clf_name,X_train,y_train_5,cv=3)
```

`cross_val_score` gives score for each fold. while `cross_val_predict` gives prediction for each fold.

Comment: Yes, I'm using sklearn.I know that `cross_val_predict` returns the predicted values. I want to get the metrics values as well as predicted values. Is it possible to get both using a single function.

Comment: I doubt it would.There isn't scoring argument for cross_val_print. So unfortunately you've to use both of them once , I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since I need also this feature in scikit-learn, I've hacked the code in my sklearn repo.
If you still need this, you can find this on my github, on the branch group_cv:

https://github.com/robbisg/scikit-learn/tree/group_cv

The modified cross_validate function is here:
https://github.com/robbisg/scikit-learn/blob/group_cv/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py

You need to call `cross_validate` with `return_predictions=True`.

Hope this helps.